# Reference to javascript file in Content Editor Webpart

Tags: 2013, javascript, content-editor-web-part

I have site which is non root site i.e. url of site is: http:///sites/xxx

I want to place a content editor web part and refer a link to javascript file which is stored in the Style Library.

My code in Content Editor Web Part :

`<script language="javascript" src="/sites/Style%20Library/js/Scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If I pass this it refers to file `http://<Web_Application>/sites/Style%20Library/js/Scripts.js`

When I place  : `<script language="javascript" src="/Style%20Library/js/Scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

it refers to file `http://<Web_Application>/Style%20Library/js/Scripts.js`

What should I do to give the correct path to the JavaScript file?

Comment: other than making it a full URL, does it it anything else unexpected?

Answer (score 2):

If can use _spPageContextInfo to grab the current web/site url. Prepend that url to your path to your JS.

For ex.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(LoadMyScript, 'sp.js');

function LoadMyScript() {
   var currWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl; // use siteServerRelativeUrl for site-collection 
   //Dynamic loading of scripts
   var jq = document.createElement('script');
   jq.src = currWebUrl + "/Style%20Library/js/Scripts.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code in content editor webpart, I think it should be /sites/xxx/style library....

If that doesn't work, try using the URL tokens ~site or ~sitecollection

Otherwise give full URL of your JS file.

You can also use spservices library from mark. It has some utility methods to get current site address. That's a long way though...